# Index of longest word in a sentence using C#

Tags: c#, string

If there are multiple string with same length(max), how do I find out all the indices. I am getting  the first index currently. Is there a better way to do this?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Examples
{
    class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
          Longestword("Find the largest word with lower index abcdefg ");
          Console.ReadKey();
       }

        private static void Longestword(String sen)
        { 
            String[] sArray = sen.Split(null);
            int[] cArr = new int[sArray.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < sArray.Length; i++)
            {
               int j = sArray[i].Length;
               cArr[i] = j; 
            }
            int max = cArr.Max();
            int index = cArr.ToList().IndexOf(max);
            Console.WriteLine(index); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a problem or do you want us to help improve the code? If the first, post the problem; if the second, this likely belongs on codereview.

Comment: Program I have posted gives me first index of the largest word i.e. index of word "largest".I'd want to know index of "abcdefg" which has same length. I don't think I can post any further questions with such instant downvotes.

Comment: @Jacobr365 No, it doesn't belong on code review. You might want to check out their requirements. OP is apparently trying to learn a more efficient way to code the algorithm (probably not familiar with LINQ). You have a point objecting to his question but it's about wrong diagnostics of the issue. Note that the dude is new and he's trying - he posted the code, at least. Play nice.

Comment: If the original code works, this is on-topic for code review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my stab at a solution:

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static List<int> IndicesOf(this int[] array, int item)
    {
        var indices = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] == item)
                indices.Add(i);
        }

        return indices;
    }
}
```

You can then call it like this:

```
int[] someArrayFindMax = new[] { 1, 4, 45, 23, 4, 3342, 34, 3342, 4, 3342, 3342 };
int max = someArrayFindMax.Max();
List<int> indices = someArrayFindMax.IndicesOf(max);
```

Here's another possible extension method for finding the indices of the longest strings directly:

```
    public static List<int> LongestStringIndices(this string[] strings)
    {
        int longestString = -1;
        var indices = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++)
        {
            if (strings[i].Length > longestString)
            {
                longestString = strings[i].Length;
                // We're no longer interested in the indices of the
                // strings we now know to be shorter
                indices.Clear();
                indices.Add(i);
            }
            else if (strings[i].Length == longestString)
            {
                indices.Add(i);
            }
            // If it's less than the max length so far we ignore it
        }

        return indices;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd play with LINQ, as it's the C#-ish way.

Here's a fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NEFkqb

```
List<string> words = new List<string>{"aaaa","bb","cccc"};
List<int> lengths = words.Select(word => word.Length).ToList();
int max = lengths.Max();
List<int> maxes = new List<int>();
for(int i = 0; i < lengths.Count; i++)
  if(lengths[i] == max)
    maxes.Add(i);
```